# Hibernate not creating table despite correct configurations and no error messages in logs

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, create-table

I'm creating a new database table in my Spring Boot application but the problem is that the table is not being created in the database despite the correct configurations and no log error messages. Here is my model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_avatar")
public class UserAvatar {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_avatar_id")
    private String userAvatarId;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;
    @Column(name="random_string")
    private String randomString;
    @Column(name="style_options")
    private String styleOptions;
    @Column(name="avatar_type")
    private String avatarType;
    ...
```

Here is my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}/${DB_NAME}?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode = default

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

And my console logs, shorten to show the Hibernate `create` queries:

```
Hibernate: create table student_storybook (student_storybook_id integer not null auto_increment, is_quiz_completed tinyint(1) default 0, is_story_completed tinyint(1) default 0, by_student_id integer, for_storybook_id integer, in_progress_quiz_session integer, in_progress_story_session integer, primary key (student_storybook_id)) engine=InnoDB
2021-09-11 09:43:20.561 DEBUG 5684 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table teacher (teacher_id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), user_id integer, primary key (teacher_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table teacher (teacher_id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), user_id integer, primary key (teacher_id)) engine=InnoDB
2021-09-11 09:43:20.575 DEBUG 5684 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table user (id integer not null auto_increment, avatar_data TEXT, avatar_type integer, email varchar(255), gender varchar(255), password varchar(255), reset_password_token varchar(255), role varchar(255), username varchar(255), user_avatar_id integer, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table user (id integer not null auto_increment, avatar_data TEXT, avatar_type integer, email varchar(255), gender varchar(255), password varchar(255), reset_password_token varchar(255), role varchar(255), username varchar(255), user_avatar_id integer, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2021-09-11 09:43:20.595 DEBUG 5684 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table user_avatar (user_avatar_id varchar(255) not null auto_increment, avatar_type varchar(255), random_string varchar(255), style_options varchar(255), user_id integer, primary key (user_avatar_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table user_avatar (user_avatar_id varchar(255) not null auto_increment, avatar_type varchar(255), random_string varchar(255), style_options varchar(255), user_id integer, primary key (user_avatar_id)) engine=InnoDB
```

As you see here, despite the Hibernate `create` query being executed the required `user_avatar` table is not being created in the database:

[image]

Why is this and how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was because of a very trivial mistake: I had the primary key for the `UserAvatar` class as a `String` when it should have been an `int` type:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="user_avatar_id")
private int userAvatarId;
```

After this change, the table was created successfully.

On a different note: Hibernate console logs were not showing the error message that detailed why the table was not being created despite having the following settings in the `application.properties` file:

```
 DEBUG = true
 logging.level.org.springframework.web= DEBUG
 logging.level.org.hibernate= ERROR
```

But that's a question for another post :)